# Substituting components (schotky diode, MOSFET) in my circuit

Tags: mosfet, schottky, substitution

I have the following battery protection circuit (mostly it's just a copy of MAX17320 reference design provided by Maxim). It's meant for a 2 cell li-ion battery pack designed to power a small robot. Max current consumption here is about 3A.

[image]

Problem is that the current issues with part supplies have forced me to find replacements for a few of the components here. And since I don't 100% understand how this circuit works I need some help finding suitable replacements.

1. The main MOSFET (Q1, Q2). Until now I have been using IRF7490TRPBF. The replacement that I found would be DMT6006LSS-13. If I understand correctly this one should be better except that the threshold voltage is lower. And I am not sure if that matters here or not.
2. Diode D1. Until now I have been using SD101CWS-7-F. I was thinking of substituting it with SD103BWSQ-7-F since it's already used in the circuit.
3. Protection diodes D3 and D4. Until now these were BZT52H-B5V6, as a substitute I have been thinking of BZT52H-C6V2. Slightly different zener diode, but I am hoping that in this application this doesn't matter too much.

Does anyone see any issues with these substitutions? And if so, what would be better alternatives?

Comment: In reference to substituting D3 and D4: In general you would not want to increase the voltage specification of an over-voltage protection component, (such as going from 5.6v to a 6.2v Zener as you are suggesting, BZT52H-B5V6 to a BZT52H-C6V2).  On example schematics (eg: evaluation boards) the SDA, SCL, & ALRT lines are shown with a resistor at the MAX17320 pins followed by a Zener to ground. This seems to indicate that the external device is actually the one being protected. So for your design you need to determine the protection level you desire for your external device.

Comment: @Nedd Thanks. It's protecting SCL/SDA lines for SMBUS. Generally those should be around 3.3V. But since the actual device isn't my design I don't necessarily know what sort of protection it needs. But I will go with NZH5V6B then - keeping the same zener voltage.

Comment: There was also an example with a 3.3v system that used 4.7v zeners on the same lines. If you had to look for a substitute, the idea of going to a lower zener voltage would often be a safer option then going to a higher zener value, (obviously not going too low).